# No package updates shown in pubspec.yaml (Android Studio)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, dart-pub, pubspec

Normally, when pubspec.yaml is opened in Android studio, outdated packages are shown with a yellow line.

However, I'm having a problem where this indication is not shown. I've tried fresh installations of Android Studio and Flutter, neither solved the problem. On another computer with the same codebase, the indications are shown as normal.

Does anyone have any insight into this?

Comment: Use this Plugin it may solve your problem
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12693-flutter-enhancement-suite

Comment: Thank you! This fixed the problem. Maybe I have been doing this for so long I completely forgot about the plugin's existence!